# How to send callback URL through Walmart BuyNow URL

Tags: walmart-api

So we're trying to implement Walmart Affiliate API into our project.

We have implemented the product search API and we generate a BuyNow url/button depending on the user's selection but we need to know if and when the user creates a purchase to be able to create and track the order in our system.

The BuyNow url is basically a URL to Walmart store with affiliate ID and the list of products|amounts, we would need some sort of additional field where they could send us a notification of some sort (an event) that the purchase has been created with the list of products and other info.

We can't seem to find the solution in the docs or from their support (they just tell us to check the docs).

Any input on this would be really appreciated as we're a bit stuck now.